# IntelliJ JSP formatting

Tags: jsp, intellij-idea, formatting

When I try to format some JSP files in IntelliJ, all the lines start from the beginning.

What options should I change to make IntelliJ to format JSP files prettier?

Comment: 1. What is the IntelliJ IDEA version? 2. What happens if you add in body `<div>(new line here)
    <span>x</span>(new line here)
</div>` and press Ctrl + Alt + L? Will be `<span>` aligned to left? 3. Does your file have .jsp extension?

Comment: 1. IntelliJ 15.0.2
2. This code is formatted properly! "span" will be not aligned to left.
3. Yes, it is with jsp extension.
Thanks for your attention.

Comment: @DPM I wanted to ask a question same as you, but you make my life easier !! thanks for great question buddy ;-)

Comment: I am glad that my question helps someone else. ^_^

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**IntelliJ IDEA 15**

JSP is related to HTML and in HTML the children of the following tags `html`,`body`,`thead`,`tbody`,`tfoot` are not indented by default.

This can be changed from File > Settings... > Editor > Code Style > HTML > Other > **Do not indent children of:** > remove everything from there > OK

[image: Do not indent children of]
[image: Remove tags]

Now you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!

Comment: why on earth ` in HTML the children of the following tags html,body,thead,tbody,tfoot are not indented by default` ? who wants to deal with unindented html?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you do not have a line in your `.editorconfig` like:

```ini
ij_formatter_enabled = false
```

as this will turn off formatting. Also make sure your formatter settings (Editor > Code Style > Formatter) does not have a glob selecting `.jsp` in the "Do not format:" box.

The rule to not indent children of `html` etc. only applies to one child down:

```html
<html>
<div>
    <p>Hello</p>
</div>
</html>
```

which is quite common to do (so that your file doesn't always start with one indentation level)